# Closing a confirm() popup with playwright in python

Tags: python, playwright

I am trying out this [bot challenge](https://bot.incolumitas.com/) in Python with Playwright. After I click the submit button a Javascript dialog pops up which I have to confirm. The Playwright [docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/dialogs#alert-confirm-prompt-dialogs) claim this code below should do the trick.

```py
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
```

But I can't get it to work.

The description of the page.on() says: "Emitted when the page closes.--- Emitted when JavaScript within the page calls one of console API methods, e.g. console.log or console.dir. Also emitted if the page throws an error or a warning."

Comment: What's happening instead of it accepting the dialog?

Comment: Are you sure it's a browser confirmation popup, not an HTML modal?

Comment: The documentation says that playwright will automatically dismiss dialogs. So you only need to use `page.on("dialog", ...)` if you want to do something else.

Comment: The script just finishes with the dialog staying on my screen. If I write print(dialog.message) for example instead of dialog.accept() it does print the dialog message when I click the "ok" in the dialog

Comment: Your code exactly matches the sample in the documentation, so it doesn't seem like you're doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept()) code before you press on button which is generating the popup. Playwright works with the listner so you should first start listner then click on element which is generating the popup.

```
page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.accept())
page.locator(#xyz).click() // Element opening alert window
```

Comment: This does not work, have you tried it on the bot challenge?