# sync_playwright().start() seems to hang

Tags: python, playwright

Simple code I wrote:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
print('debug1')

p = sync_playwright().start()
print('debug2')
browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
print('debug3')
page = browser.new_page()
page.goto("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/")
page.screenshot(path="example.png")
browser.close()
```

And the output I get:

```
debug1
```

I am a complete noob in using playwright library, and the program just hangs on the 'sync_playwright().start()' part. I've tried running other example scripts from the internet, and all of them froze on this line. Also I've tried changing browsers and using headless mode, all of them didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use `sync_playwright` as a [context managers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/):

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
print('debug1')

with sync_playwright() as p:
    print('debug2')
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    print('debug3')
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/")
    page.screenshot(path="example.png")
    browser.close()
```

**Output**

```
debug1
debug2
debug3
```

See playwright documentation for python [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-playwright)

**Edit (specific to OP)**

As a last ditch effort, try these steps in order:

1. Run `pip install -U pip`
2. Run `pip uninstall plawyright`
3. Run `pip cache remove playwright`
4. Run `pip install playwright`

Keep in mind that if you have installed multiple versions of python, use the PATH variable defined for pip for the version of python *you want* to install playwright in. Lastly, try changing the browser you use with playwright. So instead of `browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)`, use `browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)`

Comment: I guess there might be issues with my installation, because directly copying your code and running it results in the same 'debug1' only output.

Comment: Using pip uninstall and deleting 'User/AppData/Local/ms-playwright' and installing it again didn't resolve issues for me. Is there any similar libraries that I could use for web-scraping?

Comment: @we1rdna, that sounds very bizarre. Are you sure you are copying the code *exactly*? Also, have you run `playwright install` to download the needed browser binaries?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've copied the code correctly. I also tried copying by hand, which produced the same output. I've followed the installation process, as written in the docs,  by using `pip install playwright` and `playwright install`.

Comment: Installing Playwright on a Mac and running your code produced the intended output. I'm confused as I repeated the same steps that I did on my Windows machine. I guess I've messed up the Windows installation somehow.

Comment: @we1rdna it does seem like it has something to do with your installation. Try checking my edit and see if it helps

Comment: I've tried your steps and it didn't work. I'm running out of options and I guess it's better to just move on to some other library than banging my backward brain against the keyboard. I have no better explanation as this might be just some kind of anomaly. Anyway, thanks for your patience, @Charchit.

Answer (score 0):

Same can be tried with async_playwright as well:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import time


# async def handle_dialog(dialog):
#     if dialog.message == 'You will be redirected to employer Login Portal.':
#       await dialog.dismiss()

async def main():
  # Create a browser instance.
  async with async_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    #https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads
    context = await browser.new_context()
    # chromium_context = playwright.chromium.cast(context)
    # await chromium_context.set_browser_context_option("downloads", False)


    # Create a new page.
    page = await context.new_page()

    # Navigate to the specified URL.
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/') 

    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493916/closing-a-confirm-popup-with- 
    playwright-in-python/72513920#72513920
    page.on("dialog", lambda dialog: dialog.dismiss())
    # Wait for the page to load.
    await page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle', timeout=10000) # 10 secs 

    # Click on the "Sign In" button. 
    await page.wait_for_selector('css=#modal-content > span')
    mod =  page.locator('css=#modal-content > span')
    await mod.click()

    await page.wait_for_selector('css=body > div._bodyMID.pdGridM > div > 
    div.col-md-9.col-sm-8._action4Mob.homesearch > div.service-listnew > ul > 
    li.service1.single-ser > a')
    employerlogin =  page.locator('css=body > div._bodyMID.pdGridM > div > 
    div.col-md-9.col-sm-8._action4Mob.homesearch > div.service-listnew > ul > 
    li.service1.single-ser > a')
    await employerlogin.click()

   
    time.sleep(30)

    #await page.close()
    # close the context
    #await context.close()

    # Close the browser.
    #await browser.close()


 asyncio.run(main()) # one time callable
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was solved by reinstalling and upgrading pip. I have no idea why.